# Odoo 8 controller authentication cross site

Tags: odoo-8

I have odoo 8 controller which returns certain data that is only accessible to logged users. Web site is located on different server then odoo itself. How can i request authentication from my page (as mentioned on different server)?

p.s. On my development environment it all works since im calling from localhost/index.html requesting to a localhost/getData (through a reverse proxy to localhost:8069/getData for cors). But when i put it on our real server it responds with some missing session error

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authenticate from your remote server and obtain a session_id. Once you have this, pass it as a cookie with subsequent requests.

```
import requests
from requests import Request,Session
import json

b_url = "http://yourodooserver.com"
# or "http://201.100.100.12:8069" (or whatever the ip is)
url = "{}/web/session/authenticate".format(b_url)

db = "<YOURDBNAME>"
user = "<YOURUSERNAME>"
passwd = "<YOURPASSWORD>"

s = Session()

data = {
    'jsonrpc':'2.0',
    'params': {
        'context': {},
        'db': db,
        'login': user,
        'password': passwd,
    },
}

headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
}

req = Request('POST',url,data=json.dumps(data),headers=headers)

prepped = req.prepare()

resp = s.send(prepped)

session_id = json.loads(resp.text)['result']['session_id']

# NOW MAKE REQUESTS AND PASS YOUR SESSION ID

res = requests.get(b_url + "/your/controller/path",cookies={'session_id':str(session_id)})

print(res.text)
```

Comment: phillipstack i assume i can do the same request from the client? (client being browser)? Seems great i'll test tonight and update you on the results. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I see no reason why you would not be able to make this request in any language that supports passing a request with a cookie attribute.

Comment: i still have some cors problems but i cannot see this fail since it was more of a odoo syntax issue to me:) I'll fix my cors, meanwhile I marked it as answered. You saved my day phillipstack!

Comment: Great, on your controller I think you can add cors=* or something like that. I'm not at my computer so I will update if I am wrong.

Comment: you can but its not been working for me:) Tried everything in my knowledge, i ended up creating reverse proxy as mentioned in description

Comment: Maybe the cors restriction is on the client side. Just guessing.

Comment: hmm do you mean i should add accept header to request as well? I've always been clumsy around CORS

Comment: It's possible, I'm the same, CORS comes up here or there for me and I usually weave and dodge my way through it. It could be your proxy as well, maybe the response origin is different than the requested Url host and that is tripping the cors error

Comment: my html where i send requests from is at localhost/index.html whereas odoo is on localhost:8069 thougth that's the point of proxy to circumvent the same origin policy.

Comment: Well sounds like you will get through it. Please update with what works for you.